# I Want to get Next <li> Element from Mixed List of Other Tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a side bar of my website where I make next button for next page but it will not work if any other tag come.

I tried this, It is working well but after 5th Link it is not fetching sixth element. it is fetching heading class tag and return null

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <li class="heading">Topic 1</li>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class ="active">Link5</a></li>

    <li class="heading">Topic 2</li>
        <li><a href="#">Link6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link10</a></li>

    <li class="heading">Topic 3</li>
        <li><a href="#">Link11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link15</a></li>
</div>
```

```js
 function nextpage() {
    var x = document.getElementById("active").parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild; 
    document.getElementById("next").href = x;
  }
```

Comment: The `firstElementChild` « returns an element's first child Element, or null if there are no child elements.«  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild

Comment: Why are you setting the `href` property of an html element to another element? `href` should be a `string`, not an `Element`.

Answer (score 1):

One point is that you create a class named active in HTML, but you are looking for an id named active in JavaScript.

Another point , It seems like your JavaScript code is trying to find the next page link based on the element with the "active" class. However, your code might be encountering an issue because the sixth link has a different structure than the previous ones.

Instead of relying on the "active" class, you can use a more generic approach to find the next link. Here's an updated version of your JavaScript function:

```
function nextpage() {
var activeLink = document.querySelector('.sidebar a.active');
var nextLink = activeLink.parentElement.nextElementSibling.querySelector('a');

if (nextLink) {
    document.getElementById("next").href = nextLink.href;
} else {
    console.log("No next link found.");
}}
```